# AttributeError while using scikit tool

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here I am using scikit learn to classify a model and I am giving the training data along with the program I am using below.

```
from sklearn import tree

#Training data

#weight --- texture  ---  label

#150g        bumpy       orange
#170           "           "
#140         smooth      apple
#130           "           "

features = [[140,1],[130,1],[150,0],[170,0]]
labels = [0,0,1,1]
clf = tree.DecisionClassifier()
clf = tree.fit(features , labels)
print (clf.predict([150 , 0]))
```

We can see the training data and the output of this program should predict the corresponding fruit and according to data we have taken `orange = 0 and apple =1`

But during the execution I encounted with the following error

```
C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\KIRAN\Scikit-Classifier>python fruit-classifier.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fruit-classifier.py", line 14, in <module>
    clf = tree.DecisionClassifier()
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree' has no attribute 'DecisionClassifier'
```

Any solutions to solve this problem because I have tried installing the modules `numpy and scikit` again but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `DecisionClassifier` by `DecisionTreeClassifier`.

`DecisionClassifier` does not exist in `sklearn`.